# Why won't colours display on my navigations bar

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to style my navigation bar with different colors for each list item.
Here is the html code

```
 <ul>
        <li id="item1"><a href="index.html">Home </a></li>
        <li id="item2"><a href="about.html"> About </a></li>
        <li id="item3"><a href="news.html"> News </a></li>
        <li id="item4"><a href="video.html"> Video </a></li>
        <li id="item5"><a href="donate.html"> Donate </a></li>
        <li class="part"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li> 
    </ul>
```

And here is the css code

```
#item1{background:#7375D8};
#item2{background:#4E51D8};
#item3{background:#1A1EB2};
#item4{background:#303285};
#item5{background:#080b74};
#header ul li.part
{

    background:#689AD3;

}
```

For some reason only item 1 and li.part are actually displaying the colors correctly , the rest display nothing  in all browsers.
Dreamweaver however is displaying all the colors in the preview section so I have no clue what the problem is with them .

Many thanks for your contributions.

Comment: which browser are you using for testing?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a syntax error! The semicolons should be inside the curly braces!

```
#item1{background-color:#7375D8;}
#item2{background-color:#4E51D8;}
#item3{background-color:#1A1EB2;}
#item4{background-color:#303285;}
#item5{background-color:#080b74;}
#header ul li.part
{
    background-color:#689AD3;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that Dreamweaver didn't catch / didn't care about a syntax error like that

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed the semicolons properly, it was outside the braces so thats the reason it was not working. See the css rules below for correct one.

Write your css like below:

```
#item1{background:#7375D8;}
#item2{background:#4E51D8;}
#item3{background:#1A1EB2;}
#item4{background:#303285;}
#item5{background:#080b74;}
#header ul li.part{background:#689AD3;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the semi colons should be before the closing brace for each style.   the unclosed tags are causing the problem

Comment: yeah it wasn't till i made a test page that i saw what was going on.